# What's the meaning of "coming to the end of yourself"?

Tags: meaning

So, what does it mean to come to the end of yourself? Is is related to getting to the point where you are powerless? Or maybe to the fact that you are sick of yourself? Am I even close?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't give any indication of the context where you've seen this, so it's hard to say for sure. But after Googling ["coming to the end of myself"](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&q=%22coming%20to%20the%20end%20of%20myself%22), it seems to be a phrase oft-used in the realm of Christian theology. There were pages and pages of hits, and almost all of them had words like *ministry, God, devotion, Jesus, faith, pastor,* or *Bible study* readily visable in the few short lines Google displayed:

[image]

It seems like the definition Alissa gives in her [blog](http://www.alissabc.com/2009_10_01_archive.html) seems as good as any:

> *I am coming to the end of myself .. I am reaching that inevitable point when I realize that I AM NOT IN CONTROL.*

I'd guess this phrase has roots in the words of Jesus:

> If anyone wishes to come after Me, he must **deny himself**, and take up his cross and follow Me.
>   <sup>(Matt 16:24)</sup>

Sometimes this is a process, not an instant transformation, and it looks like many Christians refer to this process as "coming to the end of myself" (in order to be more devoted to Him).

Answer (score 1):

To reach a "negative" point so that you feel you cannot go on. You run out of hope, or of energy, or of strength, etc.

Answer (score 1):

To come to the end of yourself means to have had enough of your bad actions, ways. or habits. In addition, it is an expression used to say that you need help from comrades - but mostly, God.

Answer (score 0):

It's about having spent months looking back on your life, as far as you can go and seeing yourself as you really are.....selfish, arrogant, narcissistic, prideful, hurtful, liar, thief, a tittltetailer and all the bad truths.....and then falling down in absolute grief sobbing all day and begging for forgiveness. And then it's about praying for all those souls that you hurt and destroyed and asking God to save them from eternal destruction because for some reason you are unable to ask them to forgive you. They may have been school friends whom you bullied or family whom you fought with. These folk may have gone out to another country and are uncontactable. This is what has brought you to the end of self.......the realization that you are a filthy rag.

Answer (score 0):

The finite, "the end of myself", must give way to the Infinite "where God begins", if I am to experience miraculous wonder and love beyond my ability to create or sustain.

Comment: Hello @Chad Addie, welcome to **English Language & Usage**. Thanks for the response, but can you provide evidence that this is exactly what the questioner was looking for? If it's conjecture on your part, please indicate. If not, please cite the source(s) which back-up your assertion. _Thanks!_